# Unresolved Type Conflict with Same Type + Generics Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, reactive-cocoa

I wrote a helper class for `UICollectionView` that performs two-way binding between the models and the view that defines a generic type `T`

```
public class CollectionViewBinder<T>: NSObject, 
    UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CollectionBinderDataSource
```

where the initializer looks like:

```
public init(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                dataSignal: SignalProducer<[[T]], NoError>, 
       supplementarySignal: SignalProducer<[[T]], NoError>?)
```

I'm using this class to build a form library of mine and I define the binding helper as `CollectionViewBinder<Element>` where element is the class of the data models which would make both the `dataSignal` and `supplementarySignal` parameters be of type `SignalProducer<[[Element]], NoError>` and `SignalProducer<[[Element]], NoError>?` respectively. External to the binder class, I have a mutable property:

```
let cellElements: MutableProperty<[[Element]]> = MutableProperty([])
```

however when I pass `cellElements.producer` (which is of type `SignalProducer<[[Element]], NoError>` into my helper class, I get a type error

> Cannot convert value of type 'SignalProducer<[[Element]], NoError>' (aka 'SignalProducer>, NoError>') to expected argument type 'SignalProducer<[[]], NoError>' (aka 'SignalProducer>>, NoError>')

Why is there a conflict here? Both my generic parameter to my `CollectionViewBinder` class and my property are defined as the `Element` type so the compiler should be able to resolve that the type of `SignalProducer` I'm passing in is identical to the required type.

Is it because in the context of the `MutableProperty` declaration, the generic parameter is defined as `[[Element]]` whereas with the binder, the generic parameter is just `Element`? And if that's the case, how do you get around that? Since the binder already depends on ReactiveCocoa, making the `dataSignal` parameter be something like `SignalProducer<[[MutableProperty<T>]], NoError>` and then the `cellElement` property in my form class be of type `[[MutableProperty<Element>]]`

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem using artificial type declarations going along your lines, but it does not create the error.  Can you maybe update the question with playground code that reproduces it?

Comment: Sure I definitely can. I'll update the question in a second.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Figured it out, I had a type declaration wrong in a dependency of one my classes.